# Is there a way to use a default template argument without having to use <> in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a struct being used somewhere which is declared as:

```
struct Foo
{
someArray[64];
//...other stuff
};
```

It is used extensively in many places, and I would like to change it to this:

```
template <size_t N = 64>
struct Foo
{
someArray[N];
//...other stuff
};
```

because there is one place (well four to be exact) where this struct needs to be used with a 128 byte array for correctness, but the penalty it introduces for ALL the other uses is not worth paying. In providing a default template argument I was hoping it would go through transparently, except for those in the know-how who need a wider internal array which would then declare `Foo<128>`. Unfortunately, it seems to force every use of it to say `Foo<>`. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot omit the angular brackets when instantiating a class template.

However, you can give a different name to your `Foo` class template (say, `FooN`) and then provide a type alias such as:

```
typedef FooN<> Foo;
```

This way, clients who were using the original, non-template version of `Foo` won't have to be changed, and clients that need the flexibility of overriding the default `N` can use the generic class template:

```
FooN<128> obj;
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question first: No there isn't a way to use it without `<>`. However that doesn't mean you can't do something else to keep your codebase intact.

The easiest solution is to rename templated variant to something else and provide a Typedef for the name `Foo`:

```
template <size_t N = 64>
struct GenericFoo
{
someArray[N];
//...other stuff
};
typedef GenericFoo<64> Foo;
```

This way you can keep using `Foo` in all the other instances and have the option of using `GenericFoo<Whatever>` when you need fine grained control.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace generic
{
  template <int N> class Foo {};
}

// user code

typedef generic::Foo<64> Foo; // common users

// OR

using generic::Foo; // rare users
```